# How to query an API? specifically 'Adzuna'

Tags: api

I'm trying to query the [Adzuna API](https://developer.adzuna.com/), the documentation instructs me to write the following:

```
https://api.adzuna.com:443/v1/api/jobs/gb/jobsworth?app_id=1d3bc9c4&app_key=de61a42bf523e06f5b7ebe32d630e8fd
```

... i.e., the command generated by entering my `Application ID`<sup>1</sup> and `Application Keys`<sup>2</sup> into [this example query generator](https://api.adzuna.com/static/swagger-ui/index.html#!/adzuna/search_get_0)
it issues the following response:

```
[1] 10123
bash: https://api.adzuna.com:443/v1/api/jobs/gb/jobsworth?app_id=1d3bc9c4: No such file or directory
[1]+  Exit 127
```

Which I guess means that I've done it completely wrong.

I also tried plugging my details into the example query the put in the [documentation](https://developer.adzuna.com/overview) with stubs for credentials:

```
http://api.adzuna.com/v1/api/property/gb/search/1?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}&app_key={YOUR_APP_KEY}
```

I have no experience querying APIs, I tried also appending that to `wget` and `get` and still the response was garbage.

**How can I query this API in the right way?**

1. `1d3bc9c4`
2. `de61a42bf523e06f5b7ebe32d630e8fd`

---

It seems this query **A**:

```
http://api.adzuna.com/v1/api/jobs/gb/search/1?app_id=1d3bc9c4&app_key=de61a42bf523e06f5b7ebe32d630e8fd&results_per_page=20&what=javascript%20developer&content-type=application/json
```

will work when put into a browser, a simple copy of my credentials into the example:

```
http://api.adzuna.com/v1/api/jobs/gb/search/1?app_id={YOUR API ID}&app_key={YOUR API KEY}&results_per_page=20&what=javascript%20developer&content-type=application/json
```

but is there a way to execute that without a browser? directly in the terminal- to expedite the process.

but when I tried query **A** with `wget` I got:

[image]

Comment: `bash`?  `No such file or directory`?  What are you using to query this API?  It looks like a REST API, what are you using to make the HTTP requests?  What is the server's response?

Comment: I tried with `wget` and with `get`- the response is what I posted in the question

Comment: Try pasting this URL into the address field of a web browser.

Comment: @s.matthew.english: *Specifically* how did you try?  From the message it looks like your `bash` shell is trying to *execute the URL*.

Comment: When I enter that URL into a REST client I get a 500 response from the server, with no additional error message.  Which essentially means either the request is incorrect (and you'd have to go back to the documentation) or the service is broken (and you'd have to ask them).

Comment: what is a REST client. is posting such a string into the browser the correct way to query such an API?

Comment: @s.matthew.english: A REST client would be any application which makes HTTP requests.  Technically any web browser is a REST client.  `wget` is one as well.  All you need to do with this API is make HTTP requests and receive the responses.

Comment: @David I tried with `wget` but I posted my results... not so good. By the way~ nice username!

Comment: @s.matthew.english: That screen shot suggests to me that the URL is confusing the shell environment, likely something to do with `&` and/or `?` characters.  Try surrounding the entire URL with quotes.

Comment: Are you still interested in this? I have an example accessing the Adzuna api in R.

Comment: yes- I am, can I check it out?